# Delphi: implement server soap by wsdl / xsd

Tags: web-services, delphi, soap, xsd, wsdl

I have a [wsdl](https://github.com/italia/fatturapa-php-sdk/blob/master/SDICOOP/server/RicezioneFatture_v1.0.wsdl) and [xsd](https://github.com/italia/fatturapa-php-sdk/blob/master/SDICOOP/server/RicezioneTypes_v1.0.xsd) of soap server to implement.

Delphi has a wizard for create the client interface by importing a wsdl, but i want create the server from the wsdl (just the types and the method to implement).

What is the right procedure?

Comment: Just an idea, I'm not sure if it's working: the interface is identical at client and server side, so you can create it using the "WSDL importer" wizard. Then you can create a dummy *Intf.pas and *Impl.pas unit with the "SOAP Server Interface" wizard, copy the interface code to the dummy units and manually edit them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Import WSDL Wizard also has an option to create server that implements a Web Service that is already defined in a WSDL document. On the WSDL Import Options page check 'Generate server implementation instead of client implementation'.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Import_WSDL_Wizard#WSDL_Import_Options_page